# Batch file to remove a chrome extension

Tags: windows, google-chrome, batch-file, google-chrome-extension

I have an extension installed in Google Chrome. how can I remove (or uninstall) the extension using windows batch file? By running the batch file, the extension should be uninstalled from the browser.

Comment: If you were before Chrome 36.0.1960.0, you could remove extension(s) from command-line using the  `--uninstall-extension` flag

Comment: I have latest chrome browser, chrome browser gets updated automatically. no one would have 36 version of chrome. Could u tell me how to uninstall the extension in the latest version of chrome.

Comment: If you don't mind disabling instead of removing, try `--disable-extensions`. This is the closest option you can get from a **command-line**. But if you use Javascript, then you **can** remove extensions. Also, abbreviations like `u`, `thx`, `plz` are not recommended in Stack Exchange sites, please avoid using them.

Comment: Questions asking "Can I do X? / Is it possible to do X?" are rarely appropriate for the Stack Exchange format. The answer is usually "yes", but sometimes "no". Either way, it's usually not very effective. In addition, what is usually meant is "How can I do X?", which will often, but not always, be too broad for the Stack Overflow format.